# call gateway (like Twilio) but for international users

Tags: api, telephony

I have looked at both cloudvox and Twilio while looking for a phone gateway (please note that I am **not** talking about an SMS gateway). The problem with cloudvox is that it supports outbound calls only for US/Canada. While Twilio fixes this problem, it still requires the billing address to be in US/Canada.

Is there a gateway for international users (more specifically for UK)? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks :) I hope someone can answer this too, I have been searching like crazy but no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the question is not generating enough replies (or any replies at all) ;-). So, here’s what I did, I managed to arrange a US address and phone number (google it, there are ways to do it) and used that to sign up on [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

may be it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

A rather late replay but you might want to look at Aculab Cloud (cloud.aculab.com) - the first public beta was released in Feb and a second is due May time.  Amongst other things it will act as an international gateway...feedback welcomed :-)